# software that will read feeds aloud

Tags: rss

I have asked this question before but it seems that you misunderstood it for an rss reader.
What I want to know is the software that can read to me the contents of the rss feeds, so that I won't have to read, I'll just listen to what the speaker will say.
And please I want the free software.

Comment: What platform do you want your software for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextAloud http://www.nextup.com/index.html will also do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Ivona Reader](http://www.ivona.com/reader_about.php) is a text to speech software with RSS support.

- Aloud text reading from any program and any file,
- Converting text into mp3 files for later listening,
- Adjust reading speed, pitch, and pronunciation,
- Integration with any application,
- Webpages reader,
- Emails reader,
- **RSS reader**,
- Organizer and reminder,
- A professional film voice talent,
- Simple activation of aquired IVONA voices,
- Supporting of all SAPI5 voices,
- Easy installation.

*Ivona reader costs $29*